# How to repeat a header in all pages

Tags: header-footer

How to repeat the header in all pages?

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mwe}%%<-- only for example text, not necessary for real document

\usepackage{lastpage}%% <-- package to remember how many pages are in document (requires two runs of LaTeX)
\usepackage{fancyhdr}%% <-- very nice package for headers and footers of each page
\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\renewcommand\footrulewidth{0pt}
%% setting the header and footers           
%% read the documentation for `fancyhdr`    
%% this isn't the only way to approach this.
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{}
\lfoot{}
%% OK, probably fancier than you need, but it gives you an idea 
%% that these things can be done according to pages             
%% This doesn't have to be an if/then/else statement.           
\cfoot{\ifnum\thepage=1\relax Copyright blah blah blah\else Something else\fi}
\rfoot{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}%% 

%% A way to store this information.  Yes, LaTeX has its own 
%% internals for these sorts of things.  I just want to show
%% alternatives.                                            
\newcommand\mytitle{THIS IS MY TITLE}
\newcommand\mysubtitle{this is my subtitle}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (TL) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (TR) at (\columnwidth,0);
  \node[anchor=north west,draw,inner sep=0pt] (PIC) at (TL) {\includegraphics[width=2in]{example-image-a}};
  \coordinate (BR) at (PIC.south-|TR);
  \coordinate (CR) at (PIC.east-|TR);
  \draw (TL) rectangle (BR);
  \draw (PIC.east) -- (CR);
  \path (PIC.east) -- node[midway] {\mytitle}    (TR);
  \path (PIC.east) -- node[midway] {\mysubtitle} (BR);
\end{tikzpicture}


{\centering\Large 
  \mytitle\ Again
\par\addvspace{2ex}}
%% \par triggers \centering to take effect             
%% parentheses prevent this from effecting the rest of 
%% the document.                                       

  ARMA virumque cano, Troiae qui primus ab oris
  Italiam, fato profugus, Laviniaque venit
  litora, multum ille et terris iactatus et alto
  vi superum saevae memorem Iunonis ob iram;
  multa quoque et bello passus, dum conderet urbem,
  inferretque deos Latio, genus unde Latinum,
  Albanique patres, atque altae moenia Romae.

  Musa, mihi causas memora, quo numine laeso,
  quidve dolens, regina deum tot volvere casus
  insignem pietate virum, tot adire labores
  impulerit.  Tantaene animis caelestibus irae?

  Urbs antiqua fuit, Tyrii tenuere coloni,
  Karthago, Italiam contra Tiberinaque longe
  ostia, dives opum studiisque asperrima belli;
  quam Iuno fertur terris magis omnibus unam
  posthabita coluisse Samo; hic illius arma,
  hic currus fuit; hoc regnum dea gentibus esse,
  si qua fata sinant, iam tum tenditque fovetque.
  Progeniem sed enim Troiano a sanguine duci
  audierat, Tyrias olim quae verteret arces;
  hinc populum late regem belloque superbum
  venturum excidio Libyae:  sic volvere Parcas.
  Id metuens, veterisque memor Saturnia belli,
  prima quod ad Troiam pro caris gesserat Argis---
  necdum etiam causae irarum saevique dolores
  exciderant animo:  manet alta mente repostum
  iudicium Paridis spretaeque iniuria formae,
  et genus invisum, et rapti Ganymedis honores.
  His accensa super, iactatos aequore toto
  Troas, reliquias Danaum atque immitis Achilli,
  arcebat longe Latio, multosque per annos
  errabant, acti fatis, maria omnia circum.
  Tantae molis erat Romanam condere gentem!

  Vix e conspectu Siculae telluris in altum
  vela dabant laeti, et spumas salis aere ruebant,
  cum Iuno, aeternum servans sub pectore volnus,
  haec secum:  'Mene incepto desistere victam,
  nec posse Italia Teucrorum avertere regem?
  Quippe vetor fatis.  Pallasne exurere classem
  Argivom atque ipsos potuit submergere ponto,
  unius ob noxam et furias Aiacis Oilei?

\vspace*{\fill}

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[height=3in]{example-image}
\end{center}

\pagebreak

something else

\end{document}
```

Comment: The best way to set the header depends on the used `\documentclass`. Can you please provide a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) starting at `\documentclass` and ending at `\end{document}`?

Comment: I didn't understand, i public all code now, can you help me?

Comment: Just include your code in the argument of one of `\lhead`, `\chead` or `\rhead` (depending on where you want it). Then it'll show in the header of each page. Should the contents of that `tikzpicture` ever change?

Comment: I need repeat the header, in all pages

Comment: This code was provided by @A.Ellett in  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/453658/43317.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a bad idea (at least with the current size of it) but the following places your thingy into every header:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % <--- This line changed
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mwe}%%<-- only for example text, not necessary for real document

\usepackage{lastpage}%% <-- package to remember how many pages are in document (requires two runs of LaTeX)
\usepackage{fancyhdr}%% <-- very nice package for headers and footers of each page
\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\renewcommand\footrulewidth{0pt}
%% setting the header and footers           
%% read the documentation for `fancyhdr`    
%% this isn't the only way to approach this.
\lhead{}
\chead{\usebox\MyHeaderContent} % <--- This line changed
\rhead{}
\lfoot{}
%% OK, probably fancier than you need, but it gives you an idea 
%% that these things can be done according to pages             
%% This doesn't have to be an if/then/else statement.           
\cfoot{\ifnum\thepage=1\relax Copyright blah blah blah\else Something else\fi}
\rfoot{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}%% 

%% A way to store this information.  Yes, LaTeX has its own 
%% internals for these sorts of things.  I just want to show
%% alternatives.                                            
\newcommand\mytitle{THIS IS MY TITLE}
\newcommand\mysubtitle{this is my subtitle}

% This added
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newsavebox\MyHeaderContent
\savebox\MyHeaderContent
  {%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \coordinate (TL) at (0,0);
      \coordinate (TR) at (\textwidth,0);
      \node[anchor=north west,draw,inner sep=0pt] (PIC) at (TL) 
        {\includegraphics[width=2in]{example-image-a}};
      \coordinate (BR) at (PIC.south-|TR);
      \coordinate (CR) at (PIC.east-|TR);
      \draw (TL) rectangle (BR);
      \draw (PIC.east) -- (CR);
      \path (PIC.east) -- node[midway] {\mytitle}    (TR);
      \path (PIC.east) -- node[midway] {\mysubtitle} (BR);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }
\geometry
  {%
    margin=1in
    ,includeheadfoot
    ,headheight=\dimexpr\ht\MyHeaderContent+1.1\dp\MyHeaderContent\relax
  }
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

{\centering\Large 
  \mytitle\ Again
\par\addvspace{2ex}}
%% \par triggers \centering to take effect             
%% parentheses prevent this from effecting the rest of 
%% the document.                                       

  ARMA virumque cano, Troiae qui primus ab oris
  Italiam, fato profugus, Laviniaque venit
  litora, multum ille et terris iactatus et alto
  vi superum saevae memorem Iunonis ob iram;
  multa quoque et bello passus, dum conderet urbem,
  inferretque deos Latio, genus unde Latinum,
  Albanique patres, atque altae moenia Romae.

  Musa, mihi causas memora, quo numine laeso,
  quidve dolens, regina deum tot volvere casus
  insignem pietate virum, tot adire labores
  impulerit.  Tantaene animis caelestibus irae?

  Urbs antiqua fuit, Tyrii tenuere coloni,
  Karthago, Italiam contra Tiberinaque longe
  ostia, dives opum studiisque asperrima belli;
  quam Iuno fertur terris magis omnibus unam
  posthabita coluisse Samo; hic illius arma,
  hic currus fuit; hoc regnum dea gentibus esse,
  si qua fata sinant, iam tum tenditque fovetque.
  Progeniem sed enim Troiano a sanguine duci
  audierat, Tyrias olim quae verteret arces;
  hinc populum late regem belloque superbum
  venturum excidio Libyae:  sic volvere Parcas.
  Id metuens, veterisque memor Saturnia belli,
  prima quod ad Troiam pro caris gesserat Argis---
  necdum etiam causae irarum saevique dolores
  exciderant animo:  manet alta mente repostum
  iudicium Paridis spretaeque iniuria formae,
  et genus invisum, et rapti Ganymedis honores.
  His accensa super, iactatos aequore toto
  Troas, reliquias Danaum atque immitis Achilli,
  arcebat longe Latio, multosque per annos
  errabant, acti fatis, maria omnia circum.
  Tantae molis erat Romanam condere gentem!

  Vix e conspectu Siculae telluris in altum
  vela dabant laeti, et spumas salis aere ruebant,
  cum Iuno, aeternum servans sub pectore volnus,
  haec secum:  'Mene incepto desistere victam,
  nec posse Italia Teucrorum avertere regem?
  Quippe vetor fatis.  Pallasne exurere classem
  Argivom atque ipsos potuit submergere ponto,
  unius ob noxam et furias Aiacis Oilei?

\vspace*{\fill}

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[height=3in]{example-image}
\end{center}

\pagebreak

something else

\end{document}
```

I marked lines I changed with `% <--- This line changed` and the block I added with `% This added` and a row of `%` chars.

Result (only first page):

[image]

**Edits done as suggested by @esdd in the comments**

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would handle this.

[image]

You can tweak the various setting of `geometry` to get this more to your liking.  I've also used the `includehead` option to get the `geometry` package to actually calculate the height for the text on the page.

## Getting the header right

You can get the same header on every page by adding content to the commands:

```
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{}
```

So, if I write something like

```
\lhead{Hello world}
```

Then the phrase `Hello world` will appear at the top left of every page (until I change it).

You want to place an image at the top of the page.  There are several routes to do this.  I prefer saving static content which will be frequently reused in a preprocessed box.  So that's what I do here:

```
\newcommand\mytitle{THIS IS MY TITLE}
\newcommand\mysubtitle{this is my subtitle}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newsavebox\aebox
\begin{lrbox}\aebox
  \begin{minipage}[b]{\dimexpr8.5in-2in}
    \noindent
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(PIC.south)]
      \coordinate (TL) at (0,0);
      \coordinate (TR) at (\columnwidth,0);
      \node[anchor=north west,draw,inner sep=0pt] (PIC) at (TL) {\includegraphics[width=2in]{example-image-a}};
      \coordinate (BR) at (PIC.south-|TR);
      \coordinate (CR) at (PIC.east-|TR);
      \draw (TL) rectangle (BR);
      \draw (PIC.east) -- (CR);
      \path (PIC.east) -- node[midway] {\mytitle}    (TR);
      \path (PIC.east) -- node[midway] {\mysubtitle} (BR);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{minipage}
\end{lrbox}
```

This appears at the top of my *preamble* before I've done anything else.  I'm assuming you're using 8.5x11 sheets of paper.  If not, then change the `8.5in` above to the correct width of the paper you're using.  I also assume you're using `1in` margins on both sides.  Hence

```
\dimexpr8.5in-2in
```

Any packages and commands needed for processing the contents of my box need to be loaded before the `lrbox` environment.  If you're new to LaTeX, `lrbox`es are probably more than you currently need to know about.  Just know that this environment is used to save its content in a box you can repeatedly reuse without having to reprocess the code (a huge time saver if this content is at the top of each page).

The major point in the `lrbox` that you should familiarize yourself with is the `minipage` environment.  It is very handy for special handling of paragraphs and content that you want to present differently from the general content of your page.  The syntax is

```
\begin{minipage}[<position>]{<width>}
   ...CONTENT...
\end{minipage}
```

`<position>` refers to how the content should be aligned with respect to the surrounding text.  Since this is going in the header, I want to aligned on its base line.

The *baseline* for the TikZ picture also has to be set.  So that's what I'm doing here:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(<node>)]
```

This is telling TikZ that I want the base of the picture to be at the same vertical position as the named `<node>`.

The beauty of using a box (here `\aebox`) is I can extract its dimensions.  It has three:

- height
- depth
- width

I illustrate this by the letter `g`

[image]

I've constructed the header so that it has no depth.  But now I can reference it's height when determining the dimensions of the geometry of the page.

```
\usepackage[includehead,
            margin=1in,
            head=\dimexpr\ht\aebox+4pt]{geometry}
```

The `+4pt` is there to give a little buffer around the header.

Then using the `fancyhdr` package I can set this as the header of every page by

```
\chead{\usebox{\aebox}}
```